# Setting a formula for GLM as a sum of columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to set the formula for `GLM` as the ensemble of columns in `train` - `train$1:99`:

```
model <- glm(train$100 ~ train$1:99, data = train, family = "binomial")
```

Can't figure to find the right way to do it in R...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need `outcome ~ var1 + var2 + ... + varN`, then try this:

```
# Name of the outcome column
f1 <- colnames(train)[100]

# Other columns seperated by "+"
f2 <- paste(colnames(train)[1:99], collapse = "+")

#glm
model <- glm(formula = as.formula(paste(f1, f2, sep = "~")),
             data = train,
             family = "binomial")
```

Comment: also consider `reformulate`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way, assuming that you want to use all but column 100 as predictor variables, is

```
 model <- glm(v100 ~. , data = train, family = "binomial")
```

where `v100` is the name of the 100th column (the name can't be `100` unless you have done something advanced/sneaky to subvert R's rules about data frame column names ...)